# 2 mysql database connections

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a question.:)
I have the following situation.

I have a script connection.php with make a mysql connection and fetch data from the database and write it on a variable $data.
After the script i use $db->close();

Now i want to use this $data in my second script connection2.php which make also a mysql connection to another database.

What is the best way to do this.

i Try to include the connection.php into my connection2.php. 
But then i have a chaos with the mysql connections. Although i close each script with $db->close();

Can anyone help me how i can do this in the best way ?

with include it doesn´t work for me.

Thank you

This are different databases.

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: here you can see my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your code but you could create classes for the code in your two .php files and include one file in the other (or create one class and use two instances). Then do something like:

```
$conn1 = new ClassConnection1;
$data = response to some action;
//close $conn1

$conn2 = new ClassConnection2;//
//use $data with this new connection/database
```

Comment: Hi now i have posted my code if you have a look on it

Comment: try `$db.shutdown();`